# transfer balance subxt

Tags: balances, subxt, transfer

I  am using `subxt` library . I have downloaded metadata from chain using this url `wss://rpc.polkadot.io:443` . I have also implemented default example from [subxt](https://docs.rs/subxt/latest/subxt/) documentation of transfer balance . i want to know how can i transfer balance from account a to account b  present in  my wallet  using `subxt` library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account you want to send the funds to (you need the address):

```rs
    let account_B: AccountId32 = the_address.parse().unwrap();
```

The account you want to send the funds from (you need the seed):

```rs
let pair = sp_core::sr25519::Pair::from_string(&mnemonic_phrase_A, None).unwrap();
let account_A = PairSigner::new(pair);
```

Then is the same code as the example

```rs
let balance_transfer_tx = polkadot::tx().balances().transfer(account_B, 10_000);

    let events = api
        .tx()
        .sign_and_submit_then_watch_default(&balance_transfer_tx, &account_A)
        .await?
        .wait_for_finalized_success()
        .await?;
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on that example.

Replace the `dest` with:

```rs
array_bytes::hex2array::<_, 32>(your `b` account's public key here).unwrap().into()
```

And replace the `from` with:

```rs
use sp_core::{sr25519::Pair, Pair as _};
use subxt::tx::PairSigner;

PairSigner::new(Pair::from_seed(&array_bytes::hex2array(your a account's secret seed here).unwrap()))
```